# Get-ADGroup with Where-Object cmdlet

Tags: powershell, active-directory, where-object

I've been trying to create a script to find a missing "Member of" Group in a Group. Can someone help me write the `Where-Object` cmdlet because I really don't know how this works.

This is what I already have:

```
$MissingGroup = "gg-s-MissingGroup"

$Group = Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like "gg-s-*-Group"' -SearchBase "OU=xxxxxxx,DC=xxxxxxxxx,DC=xx" | Format-Table Name
```

I need the a list of the `$Group` where the `$MissingGroup` is NOT a "Member of" it.

Comment: Shouldn't the filter be `"Name -like 'gg-s-*Group'"` (no hyphen after the asteriks).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `Where-Object` for this, you can and should do it with the [Active Directory Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)):

```bash
$MissingGroup = 'gg-s-MissingGroup'

$getADGroupSplat = @{
    # find all groups where `$MissingGroup` is NOT a member of
    LDAPFilter = '(!memberof={0})' -f (Get-ADGroup $MissingGroup).DistinguishedName
    SearchBase = 'OU=xxxxxxx,DC=xxxxxxxxx,DC=xx'
}

$Group = Get-ADGroup @getADGroupSplat
```